# Механизм жалоб на правки

Tags: предложение, правки, откат-правок

Я на ресурсе не особо давно, но периодически пытаюсь улучшить вопросы и ответы внося в них правки. И мне не понятно, почему править и принимать/отклонять правки могут многие, а механизма жалоб на подобные правки нет. Ответственность за правку должен нести и тот кто ее внес и тот, кто утвердил.
Вот к примеру пара ситуаций из последней практики:

- [Написал ответ к вопросу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/685717/revisions). Ответ краткий и пары слов и кода. Некий пользователь решил, что краткость в этом деле ни к чему, и переправил мой текст вида *"сделайте так"* на  *"вы можете поступить следующим образом"*. Правка не существенна, вообще ничего не меняет в смысле, но переписывает, так сказать, авторский текст. Правка была принята без рассмотрения
- [Отредактировал вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/180443), отформатировал код, убрал множественные восклицательные знаки и капслок. После чего вопрос был отредактирован еще раз. Основное что изменили - изменили отступы в коде с 4 пробелов на 2. Кое-где вернули капс. Правка была утверждена.

Вот на примере этих двух ситуаций несколько не ясно. С одной стороны репутация дает право вносить правки и принимать их. Но контроля над тем, кто и как их принимает (или отклоняет) особого нет. То есть пользователю дается инструмент, но нет никакого способа контролировать качество его применения.
Может эти примеры не так уж показательны. Мне в целом это не особо важно. Просто с одной стороны есть рейтинг участника как спрашивающего/отвечающего, и это характеризует его навыки и т.п. Но функция редактора вообще к навыкам отношения не имеет. Да, возможно получить привилегию редактирования логично при достижении какого-то рейтинга.
 Может как-то стоит учитывать рейтинг, так сказать, *редактора*? Какого-то оценивания правок, или порицания за принятые правки, когда они не важны.

Понятное дело, что плюсы ставить за правку или принятие правки никто не будет. Но выносить какие-то "предупреждения" за некачественные правки, за принятие несущественных правок и т.п., а при наборе определенного числа штрафных баллов блокировать привилегию редактора на некоторое время, после чего сбрасывать штрафы?

*зы: вообще не представляю, как живут отдельные сообщества SO и могут ли вносить изменения в основной функционал сайта*

Comment: Можно обозначить тревогу на сообщении с правкой и указать пометку для модератора. Можно обсудить в чате подобные правки. Изменения же основного функционала в первую очередь имеет смысл обсуждать на meta.stackexchange.com

Comment: @alexolut это решает одну конкретную проблему и один раз. У меня же тут вопрос в целом более широкий, о том как регулировать вообще применение и злоупотреблении правками и их принятием. Или что модератор по тревоге может сделать? Я так понимаю, он максимум откатит правка один раз, или какие действия то могут быть?

Comment: У нас был случай, когда за массовые несправедливые отклонения правок участник был отстранён от их рассмотрения. Через Мету.

Comment: Нужна принятая правка спама в примеры? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/108830

Answer (score 3):

> Правка не существенна, вообще ничего не меняет в смысле, но переписывает, так сказать, авторский текст. Правка была принята без рассмотрения

Правка никем не принималась, у пользователя достаточно репутации, чтобы править единолично. Такие правки всегда можно отменить:

[image: Откат]

> После чего вопрос был отредактирован еще раз. Основное что изменили - изменили отступы в коде с 4 пробелов на 2. Кое-где вернули капс. Правка была утверждена.

Нет, основное - исправлены грамматика и опечатки, расставлены знаки препинания. Вполне приемлемая правка, не вижу в ней ничего плохого, хотя код действительно можно было бы не трогать.

Comment: откатить можно, никто не спорит, чем я и воспользовался. Но это не совсем корректно, когда кто-то считает необходимым переписывать тексты других людей, просто потому что им не понравился чем-то сам текст, после чего другие пользователи должны возвращать все как было. Какое то вредительство, не знаю уж насколько массовое оно может быть.  Что касается второго случая, там исправлены то пара пробелов и одна опечатка, вернули капслок. Существенные ли такие правки - вряд ли.

Comment: @teran 1. Нет, не воспользовался. Ты просто сделал ещё одну правку. А вот большое количество откатов бы как-то учлось системой. 2. Запятые там расставлены и пробелы. В целом стало лучше. А что касается капса - он больше соответствует исходному форматированию автора. Возможно, следовало выделить жирным шрифтом, но и капс вполне сойдёт.

Comment: 1) да, действительно, туплю. решил уточнить для будущих желающих отредактировать почему текст в том виде которым был написать. 2) одна запятая есть, вы правы. Что касается капса, то имхо это излишняя экспрессия какая-то, как и множество восклицательных знаков, например.

Comment: А как откаты правок учитываются системой?

Comment: @teran, если их становится много, то вроде может автобан правок сработать. Хотя точно не уверен.

Comment: ну вот меня этот механизм и волновал. есть ли вообще такой функционал

Comment: @Qwertiy, модераторам письмо приходит :-)

Comment: *> Но это не совсем корректно, когда кто-то считает необходимым переписывать тексты других людей, просто потому что им не понравился чем-то сам текст*. Тут дело такое, все свои тексты вы отдаете сообществу по лицензии Creative Commons. И дальше сообщество может их как угодно улучшать. Отдельные виды правок могут не приветствоваться, но в целом нормально, если ваш текст правят.

Comment: @Nofate нормально, когда правят, а не когда переписывают целиком :) Ибо если текст переписан полностью, то лично мне бы не хотелось, чтобы там оставалось мое авторство :) Тут пример, конечно, мизерный.

Comment: @teran, если текст изменен радикально - разумно делать вопрос/ответ общим.

Comment: @Nofate да, подумал уже об этом когда писал. А как ответ делается общим? И собственно, я  ведь по факту не получаю уведомлений, что мой вопрос/ответ изменен. Кто-то может переписать его полностью, а я и не узнаю.

Comment: @teran, вроде узнаёшь?

Comment: @Qwertiy разве что если зайти в Профиль-Реакции-Правки, я про отсутствие уведомлений.

Comment: @teran когда твой вопрос/ответ кем-то редактируется - тебе приходит уведомление в меню во входящие сообщения. инфа 100%

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, кроме совсем мелких правок.

Comment: @Qwertiy на сколько мелких? мне один любитель вырезать приветствия из моего вопроса выпилил "Доброго времени суток!" и "Спасибо!" - мне приходило сообщение

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, возможно, до 6 символов, если они не затрагивают код или inline-код.

Comment: @Qwertiy ахахах, представил как чувак по чуть-чуть по 6 символов пост исправил на противоположный :D

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, ещё момент: в случае проверяемых правок приходи уведомление о предложенной правке, а не о том, что она принята: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZfT9.png

Comment: @Qwertiy ну это понятно. суть в том, что всё-таки приходит. А правками по 6 символов не думаю что можно всё испортить

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, вписать куда-нибудь "не"?)) Тут хватит трёх :D

Comment: @Qwertiy достаточно одного: https://youtu.be/NqlUZfOOS7E  - вспоминается :)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, но код менять нельзя - на него срузу будет уведомление))